# Please tell me how to sort the received emails by file type in the logic apps

Tags: azure

I would like to use logicapps to upload macro enabled excel files (.xlsm) and excel files (.xlsx) in attachments of received emails, sorting each file into a blob folder.

Please let me know how to sort the received emails by file type. Thank you in advance.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCHsk.png)

Comment: please add what you have tried and where you are facing the blockers.

Comment: I want to sort macro enabled excel files (.xlsm) in blob and excel files (.xlsx) in blob2 by excel file format as shown in the image. I initially set this up in logicapps "When new mail arrives (v3)". I don't know how to sort them.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a foreach loop for the attachment(s) and look at the Attachment **ContentType**.  If it is `application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroenabled.12` then it has macros.  If not, you can put it in the non-macro storage account.

[image: Screenshot of conditional]